# nested loops and conditional if with jade

Tags: node.js, loops, if-statement, nested, pug

I am trying to make a comparision betwen two pairs of variables that are on a nested for-loop, but I don´t get it. I´ll show code, and after I explain better.

---

## Code

```
for building in buildings
    for flat in building.flats
        div.table-row.search_hit
            div.table-cell.inline.short.selectable.user-select-flat
                -variable=false
                for userFlat in userFlats 
                    -if(userFlat.building_id==building._id && userflat.flat==flat)
                        -variable = true
                        div testing->HELLO
                    div testing-> userFlat: #{userFlat.flat} userbuilding: #{userFlat.building_id}
                    div testing-> buildingflat: #{flat} building: #{building._id}
                if variable
                    span.label.label-warning.content-label
                        span.glyphicon.glyphicon-home.right-margin
                        div(class="flat-value inline" data-building-id="#{building._id}") #{flat}
                        div(class="flat-value inline" data-building-id="#{building._id}") #{flat}
                else
                    span.label.label-success.content-label
                        span.glyphicon.glyphicon-home.right-margin
                        div(class="flat-value inline" data-building-id="#{building._id}") #{flat}
    else
        div.no-flats There is no flat registed on this building.
else
    div.no-flats There is no building registed.
```

OK!! What the code makes is, between the two first for-loops (hidden for sumarize) show address, city, state... and all of this is the header of a collapsable. And after, the *flat in building.flats* loop spins over the registed flats of a building (1a, 1b, 2a, 2b...). On the last loop runs over the flats of a user (this userFlat variable has as info: flat-1a,1b...- and the id of the building).
On the testing divs I use to see the info, there is at least one case that must to run into the conditional body. One of these cases is (fo example):

userFlat: 6q userbuilding: 5466a4cf20f312e003e866cd
buildingflat: 6q building: 5466a4cf20f312e003e866cd

But the HELLO div never is shown.

Am I doing something wrong?? Is there any other way to do this??
Thank very much.

Answer (score 0):

I find a... semi solution. I don´t like it at all, or rather, I would have preferred the jade solution. The way to make what I want is via javascript, and the jade code now looks like this:

```
for flat in building.flats
    div.table-row.search_hit
        div.table-cell.inline.short.selectable.user-select-flat
            span(class="label label-success content-label" id="#{building._id}-#{flat}")
                span.glyphicon.glyphicon-home.right-margin
                div(class="flat-value inline" data-building-id="#{building._id}") #{flat}
else
    div.no-flats Aún no hay pisos incorporados al edificio.
```

And after I add one hidden div for each of the user´s flats with many info, just like this:

```
for userFlat in userFlats 
    div(data-this-my-flat="#{userFlat.building_id}-#{userFlat.flat}" hidden="true" class="this-my-flat")
```

And the last step is use javascript, on the document ready event I make this:

```
jQuery('.this-my-flat').each(function()
{   
    jQuery('#'+jQuery(this).attr('data-this-my-flat')).removeClass("label-success").addClass("label-warning");
});
```

If anybody can explain me why the jade solution doesn´t work and who could I fix it... that would be nice (in other case, this could be a solution).

Thank you very much.